# use `dotnet build` outputs as `dotnet publish` inputs

Tags: .net-core

I use `dotnet build -o $somedir`, how do i make a subsequent `dotnet publish` to use the artifacts in `$somedir`?

The documentation is inadequate, the xml files comprising the MSBuild logic are a hell, and I even tried to bash my head into the desk, hasn't helped.

Comment: You know you can skip `dotnet build...` and just run `dotnet publish -o $somedir` to get what you want, right?

Comment: sure.  doing both in one step is not desirable.

Comment: @justsomebody why do you want to do that? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by specifying the `--no-build` option and setting the [MSBuild property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019) `OutDir` to the folder where the build result is.

Here is your sample with the publish step added:

```
dotnet build -o $somedir
dotnet publish -p:OutDir=$somedir --no-build
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the right answer.  Side question: how did you discover that this is the input for `dotnet publish`?  The docs you linked do not include any such hint.  (In fact, I *did* read that page before asking here, and came away emptyhanded beside a wtf moment seeing the descriptions of `OutDir` and `OutputPath`.

Comment: Yes form the description it is not very clear. I tried first `OutputPath` and have seen that it still added the netcoreapp3.1 to the path when publishing and I got an error that the path does not exist. This was strange to me so I checked if there is something else and found the `OutDir` property and there it says that this is the final output location for the project or solution. I set then `OutDir` and it worked.