# Make dotnet publish use dependencies from bin folder and not from nuget cache

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, dotnet-cli

In my CI I build and publish .net app on different stages.

On build stage I do `dotnet build` and it creates `obj` and `bin` folders. I then pass that two folders to publish stage and run `dotnet publish -o pub --no-build`, but msbuild tries to copy dependencies from nuget cache folder (`.nuget/packages`) and not from `bin`.

Is there a way to make `dotnet publish` use dependencies from `bin` folder? I do not want to pass whole `.nuget` folder from the first stage, as all the dependencies already stored inside `bin` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why do you need the explicit `dotnet build` when `dotnet publish` does build under the hood by default? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741086/11885939) can help?

If consistency in packages cache is the goal, another approach would be to explicitly execute `dotnet restore` (maybe even to an agent temp folder), and then use that package cache in both `dotnet build` and `dotnet restore`.

```
dotnet restore app\app.csproj
dotnet build app\app.csproj --no-restore
dotnet publish app\app.csproj -o pub --no-restore
```